# Merged rows of Dataset and apply a custom function on some merged columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

**Input data**

```
+-------+------+-----+----------+--------+------+-------------------+
|KEY_1  |KEY_2 |KEY_3|EPOCH     |DATA_1  |DATA_N|IMAGES             |
+-------+------+-----+----------+--------+------+-------------------+
|0000001|6KBBCY|AA   |1611826286|51183688|......|[[1611826286, 796]]|
|0000001|6KBBCY|AA   |2043826286|51183688|......|[[2043826286, 799]]|
|0000001|6KBBCY|AA   |1999999999|51183688|......|[[1999999999, 700]]|
|0000002|777777|XX   |1611826555|51183799|......|[[1611826555, 500]]|
+-------+------+-----+----------+--------+------+-------------------+
```

`IMAGES` is a `Seq()` of `Image`:

```scala
case class Image ( EPOCH: String, USE_CASE : String )
```

I want to merge the data in the table as following:
For each composite key `<KEY_1, KEY_2, KEY_3>`, merge the `IMAGE` column and calculate the `EPOCH` column on the fly, to be the minimum extracted from the merged images. The `DATA` columns for the same composite key hold the same values. The Dataset above will then become:

**Expected data**

```
+-------+------+-----+----------+--------+------+---------------------------------------------------------+
|KEY_1  |KEY_2 |KEY_3|EPOCH     |DATA_1  |DATA_N|IMAGES                                                   |
+-------+------+-----+----------+--------+------+---------------------------------------------------------+
|0000001|6KBBCY|AA   |1611826286|51183688|......|[[1611826286, 796], [2043826286, 799], [1999999999, 700]]|
|0000002|777777|XX   |1611826555|51183799|......|[[1611826555, 500]]                                      |
+-------+------+-----+----------+--------+------+---------------------------------------------------------+
```

I have already managed to merge the images per composite key:

```scala
val inputRecords: Dataset[MyModel] = /* data initialisation*/

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val mergedImages: DataFrame = inputRecords.groupBy($"KEY_1", $"KEY_2", $"KEY_3").agg(
    collect_list($"IMAGES"(0)).as("IMAGES")
  )
mergedImages.show(false)
```

**Intermediate results**

```
+-------+------+-----+----------------------------------------------------------+
|KEY_1  |KEY_2 |KEY_3|IMAGES                                                    |
+-------+------+-----+------+---------------------------------------------------+
|0000001|6KBBCY|AA   |[[1611826286, 796], [2043826286, 799]], [1999999999, 700]]|
+-------+------+-----+----------------------------------------------------------+
```

Now I am a bit stuck on how to go next uses the parallelizing strengths of Spark. I could go with a sequential logic:

```
For each composite key mergedImages:
  * identify those in inputRecords 
  *  merge them with a custom logic.
```

But this is the Java way of thinking.. Is there a better way to do it in Spark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to get the second table in your question:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val mergedImages = inputRecords.groupBy(
    $"KEY_1", $"KEY_2", $"KEY_3"
).agg(
    min($"EPOCH").as("EPOCH"),
    (inputRecords.columns.filterNot(
        Seq("EPOCH","IMAGES","KEY_1","KEY_2","KEY_3").contains(_)
    ).map(
        x => first(col(x)).as(x)
    ) :+ collect_list($"IMAGES"(0)).as("IMAGES")): _*
)
```

The aggregation can be written in plain code as:

```
.agg(
    min($"EPOCH").as("EPOCH"),
    first($"DATA_1").as("DATA_1"),
    first($"DATA_2").as("DATA_2"),
    ...
    first($"DATA_N").as("DATA_N"),
    collect_list($"IMAGES"(0)).as("IMAGES")
)
```

Comment: Is there something missing? `arrray_min`, `transform`, are not recognised. 
Also, and if I understand correctly, this will not give the expected table, but will calculate the minimum `EPOCH` for each composite key.

Comment: @user1485864 I might have misunderstood the question. What is the expected table?

Comment: I highlighted them in the question.

Comment: @user1485864 thanks, see the second code in my edited answer?

Comment: Thanks, but how can we have a chat? I am using Spark SQL 2.11-2.3.1 - I cannot see your SQL functions unfortunately. And the `groupBy` gives a compile error: `Cannot resolve overloaded method 'groupBy'`. Finally, I shouldn't `groupBy` all columns as they can potentially have different data (merge can keep any) - groupBy should be done only on the 3 column keys.

Comment: @user1485864 see edited answer, where I grouped by the 3 columns and get the first value in the data columns

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228208/discussion-between-user1485864-and-mck).